# ConvertTo-PnPPage Cmdlet, PnP PowerShell, Unexpected URLs

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, pnp, pnp-provision

I'm using PnP PowerShell cmdlet "ConvertTo-PnPPage" to migrate from SPO Classic Intranet to a modern communications site in the same tenant. In some of my page transformations, I'm getting some unexpected URLs. Specifically, I'm seeing URLs with ".../sites/sites/..." and in some cases ".../sites/sites/sites/..." and I can't determine why the URLs are being rewritten this way. I have an additional 700+ pages to transform and would like to understand this process and adjust.

Thanks to all on the PnP team for all their hard work!

**Sample source page link URL in page content**

/Accounting/Accounting%20and%20Administrative%20Services%20Documents/Accounting%20Coordination%20Agendas.xlsx

**URL in transformed page content** (notice the .../sites/sites/...)

https://redactedclientname.sharepoint.com/sites/sites/accounting/Shared%20Documents/Accounting%20Coordination%20Agendas.xlsx

**Excerpt from URL Mapping file** ("Accounting" URL mapping)

https://redactedclientname.sharepoint.com/Accounting/Pages/,
https://redactedclientname.sharepoint.com/sites/accounting/SitePages/

https://redactedclientname.sharepoint.com/Accounting/Accounting%20and%20Administrative%20Services%20Documents/,
https://redactedclientname.sharepoint.com/sites/accounting/Shared Documents/

https://redactedclientname.sharepoint.com/Accounting/Accounting and Administrative Services Documents/,
https://redactedclientname.sharepoint.com/sites/accounting/Shared Documents/

https://redactedclientname.sharepoint.com/Accounting/,
https://redactedclientname.sharepoint.com/sites/accounting/

/Accounting/Pages/,
/sites/accounting/SitePages/

/Accounting/Accounting%20and%20Administrative%20Services%20Documents/,
/sites/accounting/Shared Documents/

/Accounting/Accounting and Administrative Services Documents/,
/sites/accounting/Shared Documents/

**Command Used (PnP PS Ver 1.5)**

ConvertTo-PnPPage

-Identity "redactedPageName.aspx"

-KeepPageCreationModificationInformation

-PageLayoutMapping "C:\dev\temp\redactedclientname\pageTransformDefault.xml"

-PublishingPage

-RemoveEmptySectionsAndColumns

-SkipHiddenWebParts

-SkipItemLevelPermissionCopyToClientSidePage

-TakeSourcePageName

-TargetWebUrl "https://redactedclientname.sharepoint.com/sites/projectbilling/"

-WebPartMappingFile "C:\dev\temp\redactedclientname\webpartmapping.xml"

-UrlMappingFile "C:\dev\temp\redactedclientname\urlMapping1.csv"

-UserMappingFile "C:\dev\temp\redactedclientname\userMappingFile.csv"

-SummaryLinksToHtml

-Overwrite

–LogType Console

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Below is the command that worked for me. Note the last two parameters `SkipDefaultUrlRewriting` and `ClearCache`.

I also had to mention every possible combination of URL mappings on my CustomURLMapping.csv

```
ConvertTo-PnPPage -Identity $pageName -PublishingPage -TargetWebUrl $targetSiteUrl -PageLayoutMapping "PRODMapping.xml" -TargetPageName $targetPageName -OverWrite -UrlMappingFile "CustomURLMapping.csv" -SkipDefaultUrlRewriting -ClearCache
```

Comment: Ah, I see, by skipping default you would have to define all variations. Did you try with just using -ClearCache?